# Android EditText numberPassword Visibility

Tags: android, android-edittext

How can I make text inside EditText of `android:inputType="numberPassword"` visible? I do see that there is an textVisiblePassword, but I need numberpad only for my app.

Thanks
PS: see numberpad image in link below
http://cdn1.techworld.com/cmsdata/slideshow/3297873/img_081511-droid-security-3_thumb555.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myNumber"
android:digits="0123456780."
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
/>
```

Comment: well wil inputType="numeric" the number pad also have other buttons with it. I only want numberpad that comes during numberPassword which only contain buttons 0-9.

Comment: It accept also text but in number...when you enter text it accept number which is related to that text.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to get a numberpad like http://cdn1.techworld.com/cmsdata/slideshow/3297873/img_081511-droid-security-3_thumb555.jpg , in edittext without having to choose numberPassword.

Answer (score 1):

If you want number pad mode, use this:

```
<EditText android:inputType="number" .../>
```

Comment: well wil inputType="number" the number pad also have other buttons with it. I only want numberpad that comes during numberPassword which only contain buttons 0-9.

Comment: @mayank i think you can press anything but no one add without . dot in pad

Answer (score 1):

Try following snippet, may solve your problem :

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/myNumber"
android:digits="1234567890."
android:inputType="phone"
/>
```

Comment: the numberpad is still same, with (+,-.()) and some other buttons, which i don't want